# Why would an LED stop flickering when connected in series with an incandescent?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I recently bought some LED replacements for G4 base under cabinet light which has 3 sockets.  When I put the first bulb in I noticed it was very dim with a bad flicker.  Adding the next two made the light considerably brighter but the flicker showed no sign of improvement.

Curiously, when I accidentally connected one halogen bulb alongside one LED in the same fixture there was no flicker.  My very uneducated guess was that maybe there is some component of the fixture like a ballast that limits the amount of current and is expecting a certain amount of draw.

There is also a toggle switch which allows for a "dim" setting on the light but supposedly the LEDs are dimmable so I don't imagine this is related but may be worth mentioning.

My question is has anyone encountered this before and do you know if there it would be possible to modify the light fixture in order to eliminate the LED flicker?

Comment: Do you really mean in series? Lamps are normally wired in parallel.

Comment: Some electronic switching/dimming devices require a minimum load to work properly which when not met causes LEDs to blink dimly

Comment: @keshlam - sorry, you might be right.  I'm not sure.. is there an easy way to tell?

Comment: @Kris - That is my suspicion.. if this is the case do you know of a way to bypass/modify the lamp so that they will work with such a small load?

Comment: @billynoah: If unscrewing one bulb doesn't cause others to go out, it's not in series with them... but, seriously, you can just about assume parallel in everything except some old christmas-tree light strings.

Comment: What was the wattage of the halogen bulb that helped, and for what minimum wattage is the power supply/luminaire designed? A load can be built from resistors, but will get as hot/waste as much energy as an equivalent incandescent, and will need to be designed with these things in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the dimmer.  Dimmers and some electronic control circuitry need a minimum current to function.  Get a better dimmer module with a lower threshold, or one that dimms differently.  (PWM vs. resistive)  Or remove the dimmer from the circuit all together.

Comment: Dimmers actually use triacs not resistive, and most power themselves by leaking power through the bulb(s).  This old trick works well with incandescents and has variable results with LED.